# Difference between Fetch and Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, passport-facebook

can somebody explain to me why when I am using fetch and accessed my nodejs api - it is authorized but when I tried using axios to access my api - it is unauthorized.

This is the code I am using in fetch (It came from tutorial: https://medium.com/@alexanderleon/implement-social-authentication-with-react-restful-api-9b44f4714fa) Bec I am studying his way of authenticating using passport-facebook-token.

(client -->(login fbsdk)--> fb --> (access token)--> client -->(pass access token)--> nodejs api --> (get credentials) --> passport-fb-token --> (send credentials) --> nodejs api --> (credentials)--> client)

```
const tokenBlob = new Blob([JSON.stringify({access_token: response.accessToken}, null, 2)], {type : 'application/json'});
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: tokenBlob,
        mode: 'cors',
        cache: 'default'
    };
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/auth/facebook', options).then(r => {
        const token = r.headers.get('x-auth-token');
        r.json().then(user => {
            if (token) {
                this.setState({isAuthenticated: true, user, token})
            }
        });
    })
```

This is the code of my axios

```
axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://localhost:4000/api/v1/auth/facebook',
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      },
      data: {
        access_token: response.access_token
      }
  })
  .then((res) => console.log(res))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Comment: The code above came from the frontend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should configure axios to use your token in one central place. For example

```
export const configureAxios = (token) => {
    axios.interceptors.request.use(req => {
        // don't give our token to non-our servers
        if (isDomesticRequest(req.url)) {
            req.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
        }
        return req;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is important to add the token in Authorization header in axios. I was passing it in body that's why I always get "Unauthorized" response.

Answer (score 2):

This blog should help you get your answer in detail:

[**Fetch vs. Axios.js for making http requests**](https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/fetch-vs-axios-js-for-making-http-requests-2b261cdd3af5)

> Axios is a Javascript library used to make http requests from node.js
> or XMLHttpRequests from the browser and it supports the Promise API
> that is native to JS ES6. Another feature that it has over .fetch() is
> that it performs automatic transforms of JSON data.
>
> If you use .fetch() there is a two-step process when handing JSON
> data. The first is to make the actual request and then the second is
> to call the .json() method on the response.
>
> The .fetch() method is a great step in the right direction of getting
> http requests native in ES6, but just know that if you use it there
> are a couple of gotchas that might be better handled by third-party
> libraries like Axios.