# How to make this wiktionary query run with axios?

Tags: axios

This is the first time I use axios for queries ... but now I don't know any further, I hope someone can give me an advice.

In order to develop a dictionary app with React Native, I want to query wiktionary like this

```
let url = "https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles={word}&rvprop=content&prop=revisions&redirects=1&callback=?".replace("{word}", word);
...
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: url,
    }).then((response) => {
      var results = {
        title: "",
        definitions: [],
        examples: []
      }
      ....
      let data = response.data;
      ...
```

This query itself works ... now I would like to adapt this for my purposes: [wiktionary-parser](https://github.com/PalmerAL/wiktionary-parser/blob/gh-pages/wiktionary-parser.js).

The problem occurs here:

```
        if(!data || !data.query || !data.query.pages || data.query.pages[-1]) {
            return callback({});
        }
```

It says

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'pages' of undefined
```

The way the data from my query are organized must differ from the data received by this "$.getJSON..."-query of the Wiktionary parser mentioned above ...

But how?

I tried to work with

```
JSON.stringify(response.data)
```

and

```
JSON.parse(response.data)
```

What am I doing wrong? Any proposals?

Thank you in advance, Frank

The complete code of the query is

```
  function getENWiktionaryInfo(word, wordLanguage, callback) {
    //  getJSON("https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles={word}&rvprop=content&prop=revisions&redirects=1&callback=?".replace("{word}", word), function (data) {
    //        $.getJSON("https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abdico#Latin", function (data) {
    let url = "https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles={word}&rvprop=content&prop=revisions&redirects=1&callback=?".replace("{word}", word);
    console.log("getENWiktionaryInfo " + url);

    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: url,
    }).then((response) => {
      var results = {
        title: "",
        definitions: [],
        examples: []
      }

      let data = response.data;
      console.log("DATA "+data);
      const jsonObj= JSON.stringify(response.data)
      //let data = jsonObj;
      var title, content;

   if (!data || !data.query || !data.query.pages || data.query.pages[-1]) {
      return callback({});
    }

    callback(results);
  });
}
```

The pure call for the (latin) word "res" is:

```
https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=res&rvprop=content&prop=revisions&redirects=1&callback=?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this which would be better

```
async function getENWiktionaryInfo(word, wordLanguage, callback) {
 try {
   console.log("getENWiktionaryInfo " + url)

   const response = await axios.get("https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php", {
     params: {
       format: "json",
       action: "query",
       titles: word,
       rvprop: "content",
       prop: "revisions",
       redirects: "1",
       callback: "?",
     },
   })

   const data = response.data

   if (data?.query?.pages?.length) {
     throw new Error("Something went wrong")
   }

   return data
 } catch (error) {
   console.log("error", error)
 }
}
```

Comment: Yusuf, thanks! I'm going to keep your proposal in my mind ... but I could also see that I have to deepen my knowledge. I worked on web development 20 years ago, and at that time, there wasn't such a complexity ... for now, my code works, and I'm able to continue the development of my personal dictionary ...

Kind regards, Frank

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have not bothered you with my problem ... had a conversation here, but all the comments disappeared?

Anyway ... there must be a difference between Axios and other queries like fetch(...) or getJSON(...) - see [discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51209635/difference-between-fetch-and-axios?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/fetch-vs-axios-js-for-making-http-requests-2b261cdd3af5)

I tried to reenact this with the console at Google chrome ... but I was not able to use axios there ... I tried to set up Codesandbox.io for this, but then

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=res&rvprop=content&prop=revisions&redirects=1&callback=?' from origin 'https://k62hb0.csb.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

My last idea was: replacing this query

```
https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=res&rvprop=content&prop=revisions&redirects=1&callback=?
```

by this

```
https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=res&callback=?&action=raw&origin=*
```

... and it worked ... that was astonishing.

This different query seems to return the raw markup text (unfortunately, I'm not able to remember where I found it), but that's exactly what I need. For the future, it will be my task to learn more of the javascript details of axios and so on ...

I would like to parse this text and extract the information I need - using  [this wiktionary parser mentioned above](https://github.com/PalmerAL/wiktionary-parser/blob/gh-pages/wiktionary-parser.js) as a template.

Many thanks to all who tried to help here!

Kind regards, Frank